# Marriage and kinship among the Ainur: symbolic or literal?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, valar, maiar

Tolkien previously intended the Valar to be just like polytheistic gods, who had children, sex and familial connections among each other, but he later scrapped this idea, to an extent at least: some Valar are still described as "siblings" or "spouses" (interestingly, never as "husband and wife").

Considering that, technically, they are *all* siblings (since Eru, God, made them all), is it possible that Tolkien then intended the "marriages" and "kinship" among them to be just symbolic of their roles? To claim very close, similar or co-ruling Valar as "siblings" or "spouses" to one another might simply refer to their individual characteristics that were similar or that some of them were closer to others?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by a literal marriage? Two Ainur living together? Having sexual relations? Having children? There's support in Tolkien for, at most, "living together".

Comment: @MarkOlson yes: having sexual relations and the way Humans and Elves see marriage.